# cmd shift A in Intellij - equivalent command in Sublimetext?

Tags: macos, intellij-idea, sublimetext2, text-editor

I really like the Intellij shortcut cmd shift a, which allows you to enter an action and then search a drop down menu (useful for things that don't have a shortcut, and learning shortcuts for things that do). Is there something similar in Sublimetext2? I'm on a Mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Command Palette](http://sublime-text-unofficial-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/extensibility/command_palette.html)

<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>.